# Extracting Arabic text from a text file

Tags: python, string, text

I have a txt file that includes ['صفحه رقم ا من ٤'] which is the output of EasyOCR. I want to extract "ا", which is after the substring "صفحه رقم". I am using this code:

```
# Open the text file for reading
with open(r'file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# Extract the digit after the string "صفحه رقم"
page_num_str = 'صفحه رقم'
start_idx = text.find(page_num_str)
if start_idx != -1:
    substr = text[start_idx+len(page_num_str):]
    page_num = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, substr.split()[0]))
    print("Page number extracted: ",page_num)
```

Here is the output:

```
Page number extracted:
```

As you can see, nothing is extracted! I don’t know why, but I have tried to output the value of

```
start_idx = text.find(page_num_str)
```

The output was 2 instead of 0. What is the problem? Here is [the text file uploaded](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yh_4AaxrslR2XZY4C3Eecb4ev2Q8If0A/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: *"The transfer you requested has been deleted."* Can you include a snippet of the file in your post ?

Comment: @Timeless I have updated the link. Thank you so much for notifying me.

Comment: Do you really have a single line or the real file can hold multiple lines with the given pattern ?

Comment: @Timeless The file has a single line with the content ['صفحه رقم ا من ٤']. You can download the file and see it.

Comment: @Timeless The order of the characters are reversed, if you print string[0] the output will be [ instead of ] .

Comment: Why do you expect start_idx to be 0?

Comment: The order of the characters is not reversed, it is the mirroring property of the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is expecting digits:

```
page_num = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, substr.split()[0]))
                              ^^^^^^^
```

The "ا" appears to be U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF.  Unicode classifies this as a letter, not a digit, and I assume str.isdigit is based on the Unicode classifications.

I don't know Arabic.  Are letters also used as digits?  If so, then you could probably drop the filter altogether.

Perhaps the optical character recognition made a mistake and should have generated "١" U+0661 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE instead.  They look very similar, so it wouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the context, but you can still try this:

```
page_num_str = 'صفحه رقم'

with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.read().strip("[']")
    if page_num_str in text:
        page_num = text.split(page_num_str)[-1].strip()[0]
        print('Character extracted:', page_num)
```

Or this variant with regex:

```
import re

pat = r'صفحه رقم\s*(\S)'

with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    match = re.search(pat, file.read())
    if match:
        page_num = match.group(1)
        print('Character extracted:', page_num)
```

Both will output:

```
Character extracted: ا
```